# Custom download progressdialog android

Tags: android, canvas, progressdialog

I am creating a **Data Backup** application in android that can synchronize with server and device to take backup of specified data.

Here when the synchronize process carry on i want to show the progress to the user on screen.For that i have a beautiful design of progress dialog that shown in below image.

[image]

Here i have developed outside design  of half circle , but i am unable to create the moving line inside circle that show the progress.

So please help me how can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to customzie this using following libraries:

1. https://github.com/ntoskrnl/SpeedometerView
2. https://github.com/bilthon/Android-Speedometer
3. http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Implementing-Speedometer-in-Android
4. https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this library.

https://github.com/TriggerTrap/SeekArc